# GSSAPI: gss_export_name returns a blank

Tags: c, kerberos, gssapi

I am having a problem with exporting a name using gss_export_name, I though that once the name is exported I should be able to just print it but I am turning up a blank Literaly
EXPORTED NAME: , EXPORTED NAME LENGTH: 47

Here is my code

```
OM_uint32 major_status;
gss_cred_usage_t usage;
OM_uint32 lifetime;
gss_name_t inquired_name;
major_status = gss_inquire_cred(&minor_status, GSS_C_NO_CREDENTIAL, &inquired_name,
                             &lifetime, &usage, &oid_set);
gss_buffer_desc exported_name_buffer;
major_status = gss_export_name(&minor_status, inquired_name, &exported_name_buffer);
printf("EXPORTED NAME: %s, EXPORTED NAME LENGTH: %d\n",
       exported_name_buffer.value, exported_name_buffer.length);
```

for clarity I decided not to include checks, but I also take care to make sure that major_status is always == GSS_S_COMPLETE
Appreciate any ideas

Comment: The digging around I did suggests that you need to call `gss_canonicalize_name` before `gss_export_name`. But I wasn't able to verify that in working code.

Comment: I was under the impression that canonicalization was only required when a name has been imported from a string as opposed to from active credentials.  Either way in my other trials i did do that and still came up blank.  It is possible that the buffer does not contain a textual value and further needs to be decoded.  Hoping to have more in a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the buffer output by gss_export_name is an ASN.1 data structure not a human-readable string.  Se section 3.2 of [RFC 2743](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2743).  You'd need to skip over the header of that structure and then parse the name in a mechanism-dependent manner.
Some of the GSS-API developers strongly recommend doing this.  As an example, the gss-api patches to Openssh do this for parsing Kerberos names.  This is the theoretically correct approach.  In practice though, using gss_display_name and handling the output of that call produces more portable results in practice, even though it may produce strange results in a multi-mechanism application.  You'll get significant arguments over how to handle this in the GSS-API community.  Everyone will agree that you should use gss_display_name for producing output for debugging and logs.  The question is what should you do if you want a name for searching on an access control list.  If you can directly use the output of gss_export_name and do binary comparisons, do that.  However if you need to compare against input entered by a human, I'd argue that using the output of gss_display_name is better, while others will argue that parsing the gss_export_name output is better.

Comment: gss_display_name did exactly what I needed, thank you!